# How change color of image?

Tags: c++, image, mfc

I have HICON with white background and some picture on it. I need to change color of this picture to black. How can I do it in MFC?
I have watched some articles but it were not clear answers.

PS. I can't provide code because I don't even know where I should dig it.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have code to post but, in general, the steps should be as follows: Render the HICON to a bitmap, iterate over the bitmap and set any non-white pixels to black, create a new HICON from the bitmap. This should be pretty straight-forward.

Look at the icon reference in the MSDN.